# Where were Satan and his angels when God devastated the Earth during Noah's Flood?

Tags: nature-of-god, hell, angels, flood-of-noah, nephilim

There is no doubt that angels (both the Holy and the Fallen) had a strong influence in the antediluvian world. Satan was the serpent of Eden. But, during Noah's Flood, where was he, what was he and his angels doing. Are the apostate angels trapped in Hell of 2 Peter 2:4-5 and Jude 1:6 the parents of the Nephilim of Genesis 6:1-4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Where were Satan and his angels when God devastated the Earth during Noah's Flood?**

We know that the Book of Revelation states that the bad angels were cast down to earth.

> 7 Now war arose in heaven, Michael and his angels fighting against the dragon. And the dragon and his angels fought back, 8 but he was defeated, and there was no longer any place for them in heaven. 9 And the great dragon was thrown down, that ancient serpent, who is called the devil and Satan, the deceiver of the whole world—he was thrown down to the earth, and his angels were thrown down with him. 10 And I heard a loud voice in heaven, saying, “Now the salvation and the power and the kingdom of our God and the authority of his Christ have come, for the accuser of our brothers has been thrown down, who accuses them day and night before our God. 11 And they have conquered him by the blood of the Lamb and by the word of their testimony, for they loved not their lives even unto death. 12 Therefore, rejoice, O heavens and you who dwell in them! But woe to you, O earth and sea, for the devil has come down to you in great wrath, because he knows that his time is short!”
>
> 13 And when the dragon saw that he had been thrown down to the earth, he pursued the woman who had given birth to the male child. 14 But the woman was given the two wings of the great eagle so that she might fly from the serpent into the wilderness, to the place where she is to be nourished for a time, and times, and half a time. 15 The serpent poured water like a river out of his mouth after the woman, to sweep her away with a flood. 16 But the earth came to the help of the woman, and the earth opened its mouth and swallowed the river that the dragon had poured from his mouth. 17 Then the dragon became furious with the woman and went off to make war on the rest of her offspring, on those who keep the commandments of God and hold to the testimony of Jesus. And he stood on the sand of the sea. - [Revelation 12:7-17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2012%3A7-17&version=ESV)

Although, Scriptures tend to show that the evil angels were cast to earth and were thrown into Hell. It seems logical that some of there number were permitted to roam the earth for the ruin of souls.

Some place hell in the middle of the earth. A statement that is impossible to verify until we pass from this life to the next.

> 4 For if God did not spare angels when they sinned, but sent them to hell, putting them in chains of darkness to be held for judgment; 5 if he did not spare the ancient world when he brought the flood on its ungodly people, but protected Noah, a preacher of righteousness, and seven others. - [2 Peter 2:4-5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Peter%202%3A4-5&version=NIV)

St. Peter teaches that Satan and at least some of his satellites roam free to try to destroy humanity. Peter gives us the following warning:

> Be sober, be vigilant, because your adversary the devil walketh about as a roaring lion, seeking whom he may devour. - [1 Peter 5:8](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/1%20Peter%205%3A8)

God controls the weather and atmospheric conditions, but at times the demons influence these too. We can see this in the Book of Job ([Job 1:1–2:13](https://biblia.com/bible/esv/job-1--2)); and the St Paul has these mysterious words: For we wrestle not against flesh and blood, but against principalities, against powers, against the rulers of the darkness of this world, against spiritual wickedness in *high places*. - [Ephesians 6:12](https://biblehub.com/ephesians/6-12.htm) Some interpreters think *high places* refers to the atmosphere above the earth.

The demon when not in hell take their interior torments of hell with them wherever they go. So too the angels that come to our side to protect us are always in the state of being in the presence of the beatific vision and the joys of heaven.

St. Thomas Aquinas has this to say on the subject:

> The angels in their own nature stand midway between God and men. Now the order of Divine Providence so disposes, that it procures the welfare of the inferior orders through the superior. But man's welfare is disposed by Divine providence in two ways: first of all, directly, when a man is brought unto good and withheld from evil; and this is fittingly done through the good angels. In another way, indirectly, as when anyone assailed is exercised by fighting against opposition. It was fitting for this procuring of man's welfare to be brought about through the wicked spirits, lest they should cease to be of service in the natural order. **Consequently a twofold place of punishment is due to the demons: one, by reason of their sin, and this is hell; and another, in order that they may tempt men, and thus the darksome atmosphere is their due place of punishment.**
>
> Now the procuring of men's salvation is prolonged even to the judgment day: consequently, the ministry of the angels and wrestling with demons endure until then. Hence until then the good angels are sent to us here; and the demons are in this dark atmosphere for our trial: **although some of them are even now in hell, to torment those whom they have led astray**; just as some of the good angels are with the holy souls in heaven. But after the judgment day all the wicked, both men and angels, will be in hell, and the good in heaven. - [Whether our atmosphere is the demons' place of punishment? (Summa Theologica I q. 64 a. 4)](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP064.html#FPQ64A4THEP1)

Thus to answer your question finally: Some of the of the evil spirits including Satan were wandering the earth and it’s atmosphere in order to create havoc for mankind. It is completely immaterial for the demons that the earth was flooded at the time of Noah. Being pure spiritual beings, external weather or events would not be a problem for them just like any poisonous gases would not be an obstacle for them to over come. They have no bodies and can go through things without effort. They are pure spirits!